# show the prestashop products on yii2 homepage

Tags: yii2, prestashop, product

I want to show the prestashop new added products on yii2 homepage. I am keeping the yii2 tables and prestashop tables in one database.

For this purpose I will create models of prestashop tables regarding showing the products images and urls. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New products query is based on `date_add` column of `ps_product` table. This is the function used for module `blocknewproducts`:

```
$newProducts = Product::getNewProducts((int) $this->context->language->id, 0, (int)Configuration::get('NEW_PRODUCTS_NBR'));
```

Images link are constructed in `Link` class. You can find a detailed answer here: [How Prestashop load images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289453/how-does-prestashop-loads-images)

Good luck.

Comment: If answer help you, could you please mark it as valid? Good luck ;)